# How to pause for a measured time in Elm?

Tags: elm, pause

I am attempting to create a simple web page using [Elm](http://elm-lang.org/) which involves displaying an image for a measured amount of time, such as a second or a millisecond.

Is there a way to "pause" in Elm? Then I could display, pause, and then remove the image to achieve the effect.

I noticed the [clock example](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/effects/time.html) but that appears to update every time the machine's clock triggers a new second, whereas I am looking for something that can pause to update a set time (such as a fraction of a second) after the starting time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new `Msg` value which triggers url (of the image) changes.
And create a subscription via `Timer.every`.
You can add a flag in your model to indicate whether keep updating the image or not, if that's what you want.

Example:

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    if model.keepUpdating then
        Time.every (3 * second) (\x -> UpdateImage)
    else
        Sub.none


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UpdateImage ->
            ( { model | image_url = "http://to_new_image/..." }, Cmd.none )
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`elm-delay`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/andrewMacmurray/elm-delay/latest) package provides a nice abstraction over timers.  To create a `Cmd RemoveImage` that triggers in one second, you simply do `after 1 second RemoveImage`.